# Yii2 валидация select без option на стороне клиента

Tags: yii2, select, валидация

Yii2 на клиенте не хочет валидировать select в котором либо нет option вообще или есть option (типа prompt) первый с пустым value, а валидировать такие select необходимо на стороне клиента. На стороне сервера все ок. Используется валидатор required.

Comment: Лучше код добавить в вопрос с помощью редактирования. В комментарии ничего непонятно.

Comment: @fedornabilkin,спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

В файле yii.activeForm.js начиная с 333 строчки:

```
// pass SELECT without options
if ($input.length && $input[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select') { 
     if (!$input[0].options.length) {
          return true;
     } else if (($input[0].options.length === 1) && ($input[0].options[0].value === '')) { 
          return true; 
     }
}
```

Если этот блок закомментировать, то все работает, так как этот блок не берет на валидацию select по выше сказанным условиям